# .net core Authentication with identity doesn't run my action

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use Cookie authentication in my .net core MVC project. The process is that After Registration I have an entry in the ASPNetUsers table and I have extended this table to include a userType. After the user has logged in I can see that there is a cookie in the cookies collection through the chrome browser. When I try to redirect the user after login it fails. If I adorn the method I'm redirecting with    `[AllowAnonymous]` the method gets hit, so I know the redirect is correct.

At the top of my controller I have    `[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie")]`

When I start the application I register Identity with the following bit of code:

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(
            config => { config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = async ctx =>
                    {
                        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/visualjobs") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        await Task.Yield();
                    }
                };
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<VisualJobsDbContext, int>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and in the configuration of start up I have:

```
 app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
           // LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false
        });
```

What have I missed?

Comment: I think you need to add the **AuthenticationScheme** and **AutomaticAuthenticate** options in the call to `AddIdentity` as in `config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie"`. (Otherwise it might be too late as `UseIdentity` internally calls `UseCookieAuthentication`)

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Thank you so much. This has solved the issue. If you would like to move this to an answer as opposed a comment I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **AuthenticationScheme** and **AutomaticAuthenticate** options in the call to `AddIdentity` as in this example:

```
config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie";
```

Otherwise it will be too late as [`UseIdentity`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L39) will internally call `UseCookieAuthentication` for `Cookies.ApplicationCookie` without your updated settings.